# why do i need to pass an argument in user() method to make this code successfully run?

Tags: flask

I am learning Flask in my Internal Server, the problem where I stuck is that why do I even need to pass an argument in the user() method to not get any Internal Server Error problem

CheckOut the below code...

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/<name>")
def user():
    return "hallo moto"
app.run();
```

I just wanted that in the search bar if the user types anything after "/" in url, user() method should run and "hallo moto" output should get printed but it shows Internal Server Problem

Comment: Your route includes a `<name>` parameter so the method must have a corresponding parameter otherwise Flask cannot deliver the name to you. If you don't want the parameter then use `@app.route("/")`.

Answer (score 1):

When using [variable rules](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) the decorated function must accept the corresponding keyword argument:

```
@app.route("/<name>")
def user(name):
    return "hallo moto"
```